# How to compute fields from different content types and then show the result in Views table

Tags: views

Is there a way to compute fields from different content types then display the result in Views table?

I will use those fields in a given formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya definitely,

Include those fields in views, Take another field **Global: Custom text** OR **Global: Math expression** and that's field setting text or expression, use previous field value as a token as per your formula. Make sure this field will be below the all other field that you will use in formula. You may exclude the fields that you use in formula if not want to display.

Comment: I'll try them. Thank you so much for the ideas! :)